# Execute a CQRS command when i don't have the ID

Tags: authentication, command, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am currently developing a CQRS application that has a login page. In the `LoginCommand`, one user is fetched from the database, and if it can login (enrypted password matches given encrypted password), a token is assigned to the user.

In CQRS, the command usually receives the ID of the element the command is aimed to, in order to fetch the Domain Aggregate it identifies and execute logic on it. However, in that case what I have from the user is the email. Despite that being an unique field, I am not sure if it is wrong to use that field to fetch the aggregate, despite being an unique field.

I can also think of other situations with the same problem, like trying to identify a `Post` by a given semantic URL that does not contain the ID of the post.

As executing queries inside the Command is forbiden, and attaching the user ID from the login form is unlikely, what options do I have to fetch the user given that situation? Should I query the read model outside the command (e.g. the controller)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from a domain point of view, an `ID` associated with a `User` record is simply a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). It does not have a corresponding representation in the real world and is only meant to help you persist and retrieve data.

So if `email` is the unique field for your `User` records, by all means, use it as you would use an identifier in your command.

That doesn't necessarily mean that you can get rid of your `id` field.

You would still want to have a surrogate key like an `id` field in your `User` record, because you may want to give your users the option to change their email address. Even with a changed email address, you need to be able to identify the user uniquely throughout the system, and that's where a surrogate key comes handy. You would also want a surrogate key for performance reasons; it is almost always better to use an `Integer` or `UUID` field instead of a `String` email address as a primary key, or in reference fields.

You should also differentiate between a `Command` and its corresponding `Command Handler`. A `Command` is just a DTO that encapsulates the change that happened in the external world, or a change that needs to committed to the database. In that sense, they are immutable and should not perform queries or update themselves in any way.

A `Command Handler` (which is similar to an Application Service in nature but backgrounded) consumes the data in the command. In there, you can query your repository and retrieve records. In fact, this will be a necessity to do any kind of duplicate or reference key validations.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, as it is the one that I think focuses more in answering my question and provides a good and useful explanation that helps other people to understand what to do in a situation like mine. However, I am very sorry, but I cannot check it as the correct answer, as I also think that @Eben Roux 's answer gives very useful info in other matters for the given problem, and I cannot decide between one of the two ^^'

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that CQRS would have any bearing on your design in this particular case.  Perhaps event-sourcing might though.

If you have some *natural key* then you have a couple of options.  For one thing it is going to have to be unique.  Your `UserRepository` may have a method using the e-mail address to fetch the user in addition to the id:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    User Get(Guid id);
    User Find(string email);
}
```

I tend to to use `Find` methods when I may return `null` as a `Get` indicates that the entity should exist and will throw an exception when not found.

If you only want to find by `id` then you would need to look up the `id` using the `email` from some store.  Depending on your consistency requirements an eventually consistent query/read store may suffice but there is nothing preventing you from accessing a 100% consistent store that has the e-mail to id mapping.

Comment: I upvoted this comment, but wanted to add that not every problem needs to be modeled within the pattern of CQRS/ES. It is helpful to be able to look at different use cases and apply the best solution to the problem, especially where the bounded contexts are maintained separately (e.g. evented microservices (not necessarily CQRS or ES, just evented)).

Comment: @CPerson:  I definitely agree that ES/CQRS is not applicable to all situations.  Even DDD may be overkill in some situations.  Decent OO modeling can go a long way.  I just mentioned ES since people tend to conflate it with CQRS.  The implementation behind the `IUserRepository` most definitely *could* be a more "traditional" repository.

Comment: I upvoted your answer as I think it gives a more practical solution to the problem, and mention special important points like the problem I would have with eventual consistency, and that CQRS is not a silver bullet, like @CPerson says. However, I am very sorry, but I cannot check it as the correct answer, as I also think that Subhash Bhushan 'sanswer gives very useful info in other matters for the given problem, and I cannot decide between one of the two ^^'

Comment: @elxordi:  Thanks for the upvote.  Please go ahead and accept Subhash's answer as he did answer first.  In many instances I add an answer (even when questions already have an accepted answer) just to give my perspective since it *may* assist you in some manner.

Comment: That's very gentle from you. I will do so.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest that this isn't a 'command' but rather a read from the read model. Here's why:

You are simply checking that the supplied credentials match what's in the read model. This action doesn't change the state of the domain and is not therefore consistent with the use of a command.

But there are more serious potential problems here. I'm not sure if you are using event sourcing or not but if you are I would be very nervous about putting passwords into it. Even if encrypted. A data breach of an event store with current and historical passwords could be a real issue.

And there's more...

I would want to limit the transit of passwords over the wire as much as is possible. Adding it to a command, depending on your infrastructure, adds additional transit time compared with a traditional credential check on a membership database.

I do recognise however you may want to record the fact someone has logged in or failed to login. For this consider issuing commands like 'RecordSuccessfullLoggin' or 'RecordFailedLoginAttempt' if that is something your domain needs.

Comment: Your comment gives some good insight about good practises to follow, but it does not answer my question, as I also put other examples where my problem is applicable, and nor only related to login. In addition, I explicitly mention that a token is assigned to the user, therefore there is a write, and I can't rely on the read model explicitly.

Comment: Generating a token is not a 'write' in this context. A write refers to changing the domain state.  I suppose what I am saying is that authentication (not necessarily user management) isn't something you should do as commands and events in the CQRS sense. If you can't rely on your read model due to eventual consistency then the delay between commands and the read model being updated must be fairly substantial for it not to be reliable enough for this type of operation. (Note I said 'enough'. This is one of the strange things you have to deal with in CQRS and ES which often trips developers up.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,  I assume that when you say you assign a token to the user,  it means you write in the database that assignment.  Otherwise your login command wouldn't be a command.

That being said, I see no problem having a method in your user repository that retrieves a user knowing the email.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question and I have had this dilemma also in CQRS/DDD/Event Sourcing context. Here's some additional answers on the top of others already mentioned.

**Option A:** If you consider that you're modifying the state of a user by setting it to logged or similar, you need an ID.

1. **Use the email as your ID**. You could treat the email as the aggregate/user ID. Although like someone has mentioned that has a restriction as the email could never be modified. You could always create a clon user with the desired email (i.e: ID) though, so that's more a technical problem, achievable if business requires so without hassle.
2. **Have a two UI step login and retrieve the ID on the first one**. Or you could use an int/guid/uuid for your user in a standard way, and query, beforehand, the read side by an email in order to retrieve this ID. **There are some login systems (Google or Yahoo) that also work in two steps**. See https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/91763/google-and-yahoo-require-you-to-enter-your-username-first-then-password-why-is
   *Although debatable, it has some advantages like allowing different login mechanisms depending on the user's preferences, showing customize login on UI, annoying automated bots as it would reduce phishing attachs as the second screen would look "different" for different users. In addition, it allows the read side to return different things if you are accessing from a registered device (e.g: your logo, etc.) than if you are accessing from a new device.*

**Option B:** The other option is not to consider this as a command, but as a query. Basically you are querying a system, by passing an email and password, to obtain a token that matches that request. And you can use that token later on for actually changing the system, for example attached to a command as part of the payload, or command metadata or http header or similar. If you want, that system in charge of issuing tokens could raise events so that your domain would be able to react to those "external" events (e.g: userLoggedIn, userLoggedOut, loginAttemptFailed) and do whatever it needs to do on that specific user's aggregate.

I personally like the *Option A.2* option of having a 2 steps, so that the flow goes like this:

1. End user sends a query to read side, searching by a specific email
2. The query side returns more or less info depending on whether the device was registered. But in any case it returns an ID
3. If the email exists (or even if not, the end user does not need to know that just yet if you want to avoid sharing info on which emails exist..) the second UI step is shown, where the user enters the password and/or any additional security credential (PIN? phone number? code that was sent by email?). *Also, notice how easily a user could have multiple emails, alias, etc. with this mechanism.*
4. The end user submits a command to the write side with the login attempt, providing the credentials and using the right ID.
5. The write side (command handler/domain) verifies the credentials and does whatever it needs to do, raises event userLoggedIn, or failedLoginAttempted or anything you consider relevant for your system to capture or mutate to.

As a summary, my suggestion is, if you want to treat your User as an aggregate that changes state (loggeddIn, loggedOut, locked), you can still use "standard" CQRS flow, but you need a mechanism for the front end to know the ID beforehand in order to send a command.
This is not too bad, as this ID can be cached in the browser and retrieved automatically even without hitting the query side of your system, and the user does not need to care about it.